# Simple Online Payment for Event Registration

Tags: security, user-registration, e-commerce, plugin-gravity-forms, paypal

I am looking for a simple (and secure) way to accept payment for event registration.

I am managing a Wordpress website for a organization that hosts events throughout the year. A handful of these events include online registration, which is currently completely outsourced to a third-party site.

I would like to allow registration payment to be submitted through our site. We currently incorporate contact forms using [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/), and I would be interested in a payment solution that could be integrated with this. Unfortunately, the PayPal Pro Add-On for this is still beta. For our current needs, most ecommerce solutions seem to include a lot of unnecessary features.

Also, the organization uses Quickbooks, so solutions that can integrate with [Intuit Merchant Account for Web Stores](http://payments.intuit.com/products/internet-merchant-accounts.jsp) would also be useful to consider.

I am familiar with HTML/PHP/CSS/Javascript and Wordpress (Our site uses my own custom WP theme), but I am not a programming expert and this would be my first time incorporating ecommerce. Any suggestion/resources or thoughts on security would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We us Event Espresso for our event management.

It allows for multiple events as well as multiple payment gateways, even a ticket addon so users can print custom tickets to your events. Seems like it would be perfect for what you need.

http://eventespresso.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest  [WP Event Ticketing](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpeventticketing/). It's not phenomenal, but it works pretty well for selling tickets to events.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Unfortunately, this plugin indicates that it cannot run more than one event at a time, which would be an issue.

Comment: Ah, yes, that won't work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is not great at e-commerce,  so your best bet is to go with the most used solution which is wp e-commerce. This may have far too many options for you but it is flexible and so will allow you to get events working for it.

Comment: Thanks! I am hesitant to pursue a full-fledged shopping cart for this, but I see that there are advantages to using an established plugin. I will explore this one further...